# How can I display a gridview column only to users in a certain role?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an asp.net page with a gridview.  I would like to make it so that certain columns in the gridview are displayed only if the user is in a certain role, that is, if HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(XXX) returns true.

What is the easiest way to do this?

I would prefer a solution where I can easily put this in my ASP code and not in the page code-behind.

Answer (score 2):

I used this technique in one of my sites.

```
If Roles.IsUserInRole(Profile.UserName, "This Role") Then
    productGridview.Columns(2).Visible = False
End If
```

Of course, in this case 2 represents the index of the column to hide.

Comment: I've done something like this.  However, I have the column in several tables (and the columns are different in each table), so the column will not have the same index in each table.  It would be really nice if I could reference the column somehow without using the index like this.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few options here, although some are of a hack-y variety. You could:

1. Set a JavaScript variable to the results of your `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(xxx)` function, and then remove the offending controls by jQuery. I've done something similar using the `$("control_type[id$=]") selector.
2. Use the `FindControl("ID")` function to get the controls you want to hide out of each of your grids, and set `Visible = false` on each of them.
3. Create two separate GridView aspx pages, one with all the columns, and one with a restricted set of columns. You could then use a `<div>` tag as a place holder and call the jQuery load() function (with references to the appropriate aspx page) based on the results of IsInRole().

If you're auto-generating your columns, maybe you could just pass the results of IsInRole() to the class constructor/function you're using, and hide the columns that way.